# How to comment a file on Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

There is a comment column in explorer but I can't see no way to add any comment to a file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that the comment field is available for all file types. It should be available for Office documents so you can try this on those. Right click on the file and select properties, click the details tab, now you can edit several properties of the file including comment.

Comment: This type of comment is easily lost on file copies to FAT32 or via Internet.